# How to queue patches in Yocto

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

## Background

I have a microcontroller board which has STM32MP157 chip on it, with a development board. The manufacturer provides a Yocto BSP layer for this device and the development board and it is found on an [open Github repository](https://github.com/dh-electronics/meta-dhsom-stm32-bsp).

The important thing to note is that the BSP layer applies important devicetree patches to the stable release of the Linux kernel.

## What I want

I would like to modify parts of the devicetree that is provided by the manufacturer's BSP layer, basically add to it.

## What I have done

I have created a layer, named meta-mx-dts, put it after the manufacturer supplied layer in the `build/conf/bblayers.conf` file, and made it with higher priority by setting `BBFILE_PRIORITY_meta-mx-dts` in `meta-mx-dts/conf/layer.conf` (so that it applies after the manufacturer supplied layer). Finally, I made a file `linux-stable_5.4.bbappend` as follows:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_append := ":${THISDIR}/${PN}"
SRC_URI_append = "file://dts.patch"
```

and placed the `dts.patch` file properly.

## The error I get

The error stack can be summarized by this line (from the error stack):

```
error: arch/arm/boot/dts/stm32mp157c-dhcom-pdk2.dts: does not exist in index
```

Where `stm32mp157c-dhcom-pdk2.dts` is the devicetree file to be created by the patches in the manufacturer's BSP layer. My patch applies to that file specifically.

## What I have tried so far

I have tried different ways to append/prepend the `dts.patch` to the `SRC_URI` variable, until I got it appear after the patches directory applied by the BSP layer, by checking in the following ways in the treminal:

```
bitbake -e linux-stable | grep SRC_URI

bitbake -e virtual/kernel | grep SRC_URI
```

However, that didn't solve the issue. I also tried to make the `SRC_URI` append operation to be specific to the machine:

```
SRC_URI_append_dh-stm32mp1-dhcom-pdk2 = "file://dts.patch"
```

That didn't help either.

#### UPDATE

I have also tried to append to `KERNEL_FEATURES` variable and use `.scc` file, where I specify patches, as follows:

```
# The .bbappend file
KERNEL_FEATURES_append = " mx.scc "
SRC_URI_append = " file://mx.scc;type=kmeta "
```

with the file `mx.scc` being like:

```
define KMACHINE dh-stm32mp1-dhcom-pdk2
define KTYPE standard
define KARCH arm
branch dh-stm32mp1-dhcom-pdk2

patch dts.patch
```

With no effect.

## Need your help

Thanks

Comment: In what order do the patches appear in your SRC_URI variable? They will be applied in that order.  Do you have the correct striplevel set for your patch?  Did you check the recipes log.do_patch file for further hints?

Comment: My patch is at the end of the SRC_URI string. I have created the patch from the same level of the BSP patches, verified by inspecting the diff files, that is from the root dir of the kernel. There are no hints in the BSP layer that striplevel is different. The log.do_patch gives hints like "Patch needs to be refereshed. Sample resolution script:..." and "Patch failures can be resolved in the linux source directory ...", but I don't think those hints give clean way for resolving the issue.

Comment: For that matter, here is the header from the patch file that creates that file in the kernel tree:

diff --git a/arch/arm/boot/dts/stm32mp157c-dhcom-pdk2.dts b/arch/arm/boot/dts/stm32mp157c-dhcom-pdk2.dts
new file mode 100644
index 000000000000..af99e132e1b1
--- /dev/null
+++ b/arch/arm/boot/dts/stm32mp157c-dhcom-pdk2.dts
@@ -0,0 +1,265 @@

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm stumped then.  Haven't worked with the scc files for quite a while myself. Did you try adding the destsuffix to your scc-file SRC_URI entry? I would try to add your new scc file as similarly as possible to how the BSP does it.